# Electromagentic induction derivation problem

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I was learning about *proof of Neumann's law on electromagnetic induction*.
In that proof, they have considered a circular loop carrying current **i**, a small current element **dl** and magnetic induction $\overrightarrow B$. Now, I have learnt that only variable current can produce *inductive emf* or *magnetic induction*. Now, as I followed the proof step by step, While calculating the *total work done*, they have placed *i (current)* outside of integration. Now, it is so obvious that they are treating **i** as a constant. But again, how can a constant current produce magnetic induction?

Here is some initial steps of proof(in book):

*Let I be the length of a conductor which is part of a closed circuit shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcnZy.jpg)
. Let $\overrightarrow B$ be the magnetic induction acting at any point on an elementary part $\overrightarrow {dl}$ of the conductor. If i is the current through $\overrightarrow {dl}$ due to the emf $E$ of a cell included in the closed circuit, then the force on $\overrightarrow{dl}$ is $i \overrightarrow{dl} X \overrightarrow B$.
If due to this force, the element $\overrightarrow {dl}$ has elementary displacement $\overrightarrow{dx}$ in time $dt$, the work done by the external source (i.e., the cell) on the element is $i (\overrightarrow{dl}X \overrightarrow B).\overrightarrow{dx}.$*

*The whole conductor is free to move, the total work done is,*

*$\\[10pt]i\int(\overrightarrow{dl}X \overrightarrow{B})\; \overrightarrow{dx}=i\int(\overrightarrow{dx}X \overrightarrow{dl}).\;\overrightarrow B$*

This is the part where I am getting confused (where *i*  is outside the integral). Can anyone please clarify? Also I have another doubt related to the angle $\theta$ between $\overrightarrow{dl}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$. If the conducting loop is experiencing some force and causing displacement of the position of the wire, then will angle or $\theta$ vary continuously ?(in that way will $sin \;\theta$ also be outside the integral ?

Please help me clarify these two doubts related to $i(current)$ and angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason $i$ is outside the integral is beacuse the author is calculating the force on the entire loop at a time instant. The integration is on the length of the loop, not in time.

By the same reasoning, all time dependent quantities like $\theta,\vec{x}$ etc are taken constant in an integration over $l$.

In other words, the configuration of the wire is frozen at the instant $dt$ and the integration is performed.